# Claim doesn't show up unless I log out and log back in

Tags: asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I'm working in Asp.net core rc 2.  I create the claim, i add the claim to the claimsidentity, i view the claims and it's there, but as soon as i go leave the scope my useridentity doesn't have the clam anymore, unless i log out and log back in, so thats why im trying to do in the bottom half of the code but that doesn't work either.  any help would be nice. thanks.  [image]

Comment: Please don't use tags in Question title! http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging And don't use asp.net tag for asp.net core related question, it's completely different technologies

Comment: ok, sorry.  Do you know the answer to my question? pretty please!